# Mixed content & uri_for function

Tags: perl, web, frameworks, dancer

We have an web application using dancer2 framework.The website is using https.
But in the page, it calls other page using uri_for.
i.e The url is generated by uri_for and sending it to template.

The url generated is automatically set ‘http’, so the page has mixed content. And thus doesn’t load.

My question is where is the uri_for located. Why is automatically set ‘http’, how can I specify it to be ‘https’?

Many thanks
Wendy

Comment: I somehow doubt that. Do you have some kind of HTTPS-to-HTTP translation happening before it reaches the server?

Comment: [`behind_proxy` config setting](https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Config.pod#behind_proxy-(boolean))

Comment: In config.yml, i set behind_proxy: 1, but still not able to return 'https', on the page, https://metacpan.org/dist/Dancer2/view/lib/Dancer2/Config.pod#behind_proxy-(boolean), it says In Apache, need to set: RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https"
RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_HOST "www.example.com". We use Nginx, any ideas where to set RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO & RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_HOST?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is where is the `uri_for` located.

See [line 283](https://metacpan.org/release/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.301004/source/lib/Dancer2/Core/Request.pm#L283) in `Dancer2::Core::Request` :

```
sub uri_for {
    my ( $self, $part, $params, $dont_escape ) = @_;
 
    $part ||= '';
    my $uri = $self->base;
 
    # Make sure there's exactly one slash between the base and the new part
    my $base = $uri->path;
    $base =~ s|/$||;
    $part =~ s|^/||;
    $uri->path("$base/$part");
 
    $uri->query_form($params) if $params;
 
    return $dont_escape
           ? uri_unescape( ${ $uri->canonical } )
           : ${ $uri->canonical };
}
```

It obtains the scheme by calling `$self->base`, see [line 242](https://metacpan.org/release/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.301004/source/lib/Dancer2/Core/Request.pm#L242) :

```
sub base {
    my $self = shift;
    my $uri  = $self->_common_uri;
 
    return $uri->canonical;
}
```

which calls `$self->_common_uri` (see [line 249](https://metacpan.org/release/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.301004/source/lib/Dancer2/Core/Request.pm#L249)) :

```
sub _common_uri {
    my $self = shift;
 
    my $path   = $self->env->{SCRIPT_NAME};
    my $port   = $self->env->{SERVER_PORT};
    my $server = $self->env->{SERVER_NAME};
    my $host   = $self->host;
    my $scheme = $self->scheme;
 
    my $uri = URI->new;
    $uri->scheme($scheme);
    $uri->authority( $host || "$server:$port" );
    $uri->path( $path      || '/' );
 
    return $uri;
}
```

which calls `$self->scheme`, see [line 159](https://metacpan.org/release/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-0.301004/source/lib/Dancer2/Core/Request.pm#L159) :

```
sub scheme {
    my ($self) = @_;
    my $scheme = $self->is_behind_proxy
               ? $self->forwarded_protocol
               : '';
 
    return $scheme || $self->env->{'psgi.url_scheme'};
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. Many thanks! So it calls $self->scheme ultimately. Then next question is where to set $self->is_behind_proxy or $self->forwarded_protocol ? and $self->env->{'psgi.url_scheme'}?   We use nginx as web server.